# How to check if text is visible with seleniumbase?

Tags: python, selenium, seleniumbase

Using [seleniumbase](https://seleniumbase.io/help_docs/method_summary/) I just want to check if some text is available. I just want to get a boolean flag, indicating text is available (`True`) or not (`False`).

The methods provided by `seleniumbase` seem to throw an exception if the text is not available. Is there another method that just returns a boolean flag, or do I have to use a `try/except` construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `self.is_text_visible()`:

```py
self.is_text_visible(text, selector="html")
```

Eg:

```
self.is_text_visible("Welcome")
self.is_text_visible("Welcome", "h1")
```